# How to use async pipe form mat-option values?

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 5 project with Angular Material 5. In one of my forms I have to fetch the drop down values from web service. This is how I declare my form data,

```
formData:Observable<{
    taxList: {
    label: string,
        Value: number
    }[],
    category: {
        label: string,
        Value: number
    }[]
}>;
```

In `ngOnInit` I am fetching the data as follow.

```
this.dataService.getFormData().subscribe((data) => {
    this.formData = data.content;
});
```

And in my template,

```
<mat-form-field class="common-form-field">
    <mat-select formControlName="taxId">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let tax of (formData.taxList | async)" [value]="tax.value">
            {{ tax.label }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I am getting an errors in console, `Cannot read property 'taxList' of undefined` and `InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object],[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'`
What is the error and possible solution? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `async` pipe. since you are subscribing to the observable, no need to use the async pipe again.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let tax of formData.taxList" [value]="tax.value">
```

OR maybe you can make the `formData` variable `Observable`

```
formData : Observable<Array<any>>
ngOnInit() {    
  this.formData = this.dataService.getFormData();
}


<mat-option *ngFor="let tax of formData.taxList | async " [value]="tax.value">
```

Comment: I tried removing the async pipe. An error came, 'Cannot read property 'taxList' of undefined'. Because the formData variable is not initialized. It will be initialized only after fetched from the web service using http.

Comment: just initialize the `taxList` property as an empty array in the constructor

Comment: Then I cannot declare type of the formData Object. Can I use async pipe in this situation?

Comment: for me not working :(  `getStates(): Observable<any[]> {
    debugger
      return this._http.get<any[]>(this._urlgetStatesModal, httpOptions).pipe(
      catchError(this.errorHandler)
    )
  }`